# Feature error with eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am getting error with my feature.xml. It is version 1.2 not available. 
The screenshot is shown below.

[image]

But version 1.2 is available.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that your version number is invalid.  Eclipse expects that there are 3 or 4 components to a version number: major.minor.micro.qualifier (and qualifier is optional).

You should change `1.2` to `1.2.0` in both the plugin and the feature.  Optionally, you can change the feature to have `0.0.0`.  In this case, the feature will always sync with the latest version of the plugin.